# Typo3 10.4.28 :error in class NewContentElementController.php : rawurlencode() typo3

Tags: typo3

I've got this problem on Typo3 (ver 10.4.28) :

I installed typo3 via composer : is there something on server (apache on    Linux 3.10.0-1160.31.1.el7.x86_64)  that must be enabled?

Uncaught TYPO3 Exception: rawurlencode() expects parameter 1 to be string, null given | TypeError thrown in file /usr/local/data/sites/preprodpolimi/typo3/public/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Controller/ContentElement/NewContentElementController.php in line 262. Requested URL: https://new.preprod.polimi.it/typo3/index.php?route=%%2Frecord%%2Fcontent%%2Fwizard%%2Fnew&token=--AnonymizedToken--&id=12111&sys_language_uid=0&colPos=0&uid_pid=-63481&returnUrl=%%2Ftypo3%%2Findex.php%%3Froute%%3D%%252Fmodule%%252Fweb%%252Flayout%%26token%%3D1b7ab75393abeb7058de2411d545f582a866539c%%26id%%3D12111%%26

Comment: My fault : 
the error is located in ext_localconf.php of my ext -> wrong definition of wizard.

  // wizards
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::addPageTSConfig(
        'mod {
            wizards.newContentElement.wizardItems.plugins {

Comment: Please mark your question as answered and/or add your solution as answer.